# how to convert window form data into PDF

Tags: c#, windows, pdf-generation

I am working on an Salary Project and what i want to do is 
when an user see their Salary slip and click on Downloads then the complete form data is converted into PDf file and stored on an predifined location..

plz suggest the code to meet my requirements..

Comment: Do you want the form image in a pdf file?

Comment: You demanded everything once in for all.

Comment: @valter yes i need an image..

Answer (score 0):

I had faced this problem before, and the best I found to solve it was to user `Microsoft Word Interops`. You can put whatever you want in a word document and then save it as PDF, fortunately Microsoft word allows you to export the document to PDF.

The simplest way to do this would be to save your data as just plain text, but don't forget to well format them, and then run this method to convert the plain text to PDF.

```
public PDFWriter(String Path, String FileName) {
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application word = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
        try
        {
            word.Visible = false;
            word.Documents.Open(Path);
            word.ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(FileName + ".pdf", Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
            this.Path = FileName + ".pdf";

        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            word.Quit();
            throw new Exception(e.Message);
        }

        finally
        {
            word.Quit();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Download pdfSharp.dll [pdfSharp](http://pdfsharp.codeplex.com/releases)
and add it as reference.

Capture your form as image and then

```
private void ImageToPdf()
    {
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument doc = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfDocument();
        PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage oPage = new PdfSharp.Pdf.PdfPage();
        String destinaton = "your destination";

        doc.Pages.Add(oPage);

        XGraphics xgr;
        XImage img;

        img = XImage.FromGdiPlusImage(form image);

        xgr = PdfSharp.Drawing.XGraphics.FromPdfPage(oPage);
        xgr.DrawImage(img, 0, 0);


        doc.Save(destinaton);
        doc.Close();

    }
```

valter

Comment: What is form Image here?